# Keycloak - Give permission to a user perform actions for another user

Tags: keycloak

Is there any way to use keycloak and give permission to a user performing actions for another user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use impersonation for your request. Go to keycloak admin console - > Users - > Search User and select One user - > Click on Impersonate button. You will be logged in as that user and redirected to account console page.

To perform above task user must have impersonate role. Which can be assigned to the user from Role Mappings.

Refer https://www.janua.fr/using-impersonation-with-keycloak/ for more details